# Questions on the semi-classical interpretation of the (normal) Zeeman effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I'll put pictures from the book (Introduction to the Structure of Matter: A Course in Modern Physics by John J. Brehm and William J. Mullins) as I think they are relevant to understand my problem:

[image]

I have trouble understanding the case where the observer watches the source in a direction perpendicular to the magnetic field. The electron will rotate around B axis, so the observer will only see a linear oscillation of the electron hence linearly polarized light.
But how can the Lorentz force explain the splitting of spectral lines (i.e. the change of the frequency of the electron)? The book suggests to view the linear oscillation as a combination of two counter-rotating motions like this:

[image]

But if this is the case, the Lorentz force would act in a plane perpendicular to the image so it won't explain the change of the frequency of the circular motion of the electron (and so the Zeeman splitting, classically).
Instead the situation is clear when we observe along the direction of B, as in that case Lorentz force would act radially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the key issue is that the two possible orbits which add up to the vertical oscillation, as drawn in the final picture, should be considered as viewed from the on-axis observer, not from the side observer.

Then, if you think carefully about it, a radial force is exactly what's needed to change the frequency of a circular oscillation at a fixed radius $r$.  Equating the total inward radial force magnitude $F$ with $mv^2/r = m\omega^2 r$, you can see that changing the total $F$ will change $\omega$.

The only other step you need is to imagine that the radial force on the electron orbit is dominated by the nucleus of its atom, and the Lorentz force is just a small perturbation, either radially inward or outward, depending on which way the electron is orbiting.  One of these will have a slightly higher orbital frequency, and one will have a slightly lower frequency, due to the Lorentz force.  That gets you a classical analog of Zeeman splitting.

Comment: Well, if in the final picture the left side (linear oscillation) is viewed from the side observer, while the right side (two counter-rotating motion) is viewed from the axis, then everything is clear. I thought about it, but I wasn't sure because the book never mentions that and I also thought that when an observer sees from the axis, he doesn't see that.

Comment: Yes, I guess it was just a question of the drawing perspective, then.  Glad you found my answer useful! :-)